# To install applications in Developer view of iPad

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, xcode

I would like to install Amazon's Kindle application to my virtual iPad on my Macbook Air's Xcode. 
However, the developer view is very limited. 
I can only connect iCloud which shares some details such as emails but not programs.

**How can you install Kindle to your virtual iPad in XCode?**

Comment: There is a Kindle app for OSX

Comment: @Mark Yes, but you cannot watch videos with the OSX app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only install apps that you have built yourself in the Xcode emulator.

One reason is that the emulator runs x86 code whist production uses a ARM processor